# C: descending insertion sort with guard

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to apply a descending insertion sort algorithm with guard to one-dimensional int array in pure C. Although I've already managed to implement a regular descending sort without guard, unfortunately, I'm forced to use the guard according to the requirements. To my shame, I fail to understand what guard is used for in the descending version of this algorithm; it just doesn't seem to make sense here. I tried to simply 'revert' an ascending insertion sort: that is, in the descending case the guard element would be intentionally assigned the value larger than any other among the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GUARD 32767

void insertion_sort(int size, int *array){
    int temp, next, oldZero = array[0];
    array[0] = GUARD;

    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
        int j = i + 1;
        temp = array[j];

        while(j > 0 && temp > array[j-1]){
            array[j] = array[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    array[0] = oldZero;

/**No ideas so far*/
}
```

Apparently, now I have to append a kind of extra sort here in order to move the oldZero to its position. I suppose a simple while-cycle comparing the oldZero with its neighbors would suffice. However, such manipulations look clumsy and, perhaps, I'm missing some more elegant solution.

> Is there proper way to use descending insertion sort with guard in this case? If yes, what steps should I apply to or remove from my solution?

Please excuse me if my question is too basic, since I'm quite new to C.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Is there proper way to use descending insertion sort with guard in this case? If yes, what steps shoud I apply to or remove from my solution?

Comment: ntonk, Why does code use `32767` instead of `INT_MAX`?

Comment: As far as I know, `INT_MAX` resides within the limits.h (please correct me if I'm wrong). Unfortunately, I'm restricted to use stdio.h and stdlib.h only by the requirements. Actually, in this case `32767` is nothing more than example: my array is not supposed to contain values that exceed 100, so any integer more than 100 would be suitable.

Comment: The guard negates the need for tests such as `j > 0 && ` in `while(j > 0 && temp > array[j-1]){` allowing the nest loop to run faster - it is a micro-optimization.

Comment: Do you have any limit of the array size? Is it possible that you are expected to impliment a `shell sort` which is a variant of insert sort, in which a `gap` is required?

Comment: I would start by finding the maximum value in the array, and swap that with `array[0]`. That way you have a guard value without needing to use any magic numbers. And you don't need the `oldZero` variable, or any extra steps at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure how much that helps, @user3386109. You're substituting extra steps at the beginning, with their required variables, for extra steps at the end, with *their* required variables.  I think it's about a wash.

Comment: As you surmised, at the end you need to remove the guard value from the array and sort `oldZero` into the correct position.  With the whole rest of the array sorted, this is just another insertion.  I imagine it looking similar to the inner loop of your loop nest, but scanning from low array indexes toward high instead of the other way around.

Comment: Are you saying that you have an ascending insertion sort with a guard, and you can't figure out how to turn it into a descending sort? Or that you don't understand the purpose of a guard in an ascending sort either?

Comment: And what algo textbook are you using? Sedgewick's insertion sort is guarded by assuming that element 0 of the array can be dedicated to the sentinel....